# How to check if Array is sorted?

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe6

How can I check if `TArray` is already sorted? I am using the default `TArray.Sort` to sort my array.

Comment: What if i have 10 million elements?

Comment: You can't tell if an array is sorted without checking each element against its neighboring elements. What if you have 10 million elements, and all are sorted except for three that are out of position somewhere in that 10 million? The easiest thing to do is to either just sort the array, or to start checking for out of order elements, and the instant you find one you sort the array (which means you've now added the time to check the array to the time it will take to sort). Whether the added time is an issue or not is up to you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do it like as below. In fact, my class has a load more goodies, I've just included the code to test whether arrays are ordered. I use `TArray` and hide the version in `Generics.Collections`, but derive from it to inherit its capabilities. This leads to code that reads better, although the use of hiding may make you feel queasy to begin with.

```
uses
  System.SysUtils,
  System.Generics.Defaults,
  System.Generics.Collections;

type
  TSortType = (stIncreasing, stDecreasing);

  TArray = class(System.Generics.Collections.TArray)
  private
    class function Comparison<T>(SortType: TSortType): TComparison<T>; static;
    class function Comparer<T>(const Comparison: TComparison<T>): IComparer<T>; static;
  public
    class function Sorted<T>(var Values: array of T; SortType: TSortType; Index, Count: Integer): Boolean; overload; static;
    class function Sorted<T>(var Values: array of T; SortType: TSortType): Boolean; overload; static;
    class function Sorted<T>(var Values: array of T; const Comparison: TComparison<T>; Index, Count: Integer): Boolean; overload; static;
    class function Sorted<T>(var Values: array of T; const Comparison: TComparison<T>): Boolean; overload; static;
    class function Sorted<T>(GetValue: TFunc<Integer,T>; const Comparison: TComparison<T>; Index, Count: Integer): Boolean; overload; static;
  end;

class function TArray.Comparison<T>(SortType: TSortType): TComparison<T>;
var
  DefaultComparer: IComparer<T>;
begin
  DefaultComparer := TComparer<T>.Default;
  Result :=
    function(const Left, Right: T): Integer
    begin
      case SortType of
      stIncreasing:
        Result := DefaultComparer.Compare(Left, Right);
      stDecreasing:
        Result := -DefaultComparer.Compare(Left, Right);
      end;
    end;
end;

class function TArray.Comparer<T>(const Comparison: TComparison<T>): IComparer<T>;
begin
  Result := TComparer<T>.Construct(Comparison);
end;

class function TArray.Sorted<T>(var Values: array of T; SortType: TSortType; Index, Count: Integer): Boolean;
begin
  Result := Sorted<T>(Values, Comparison<T>(SortType), Index, Count);
end;

class function TArray.Sorted<T>(var Values: array of T; SortType: TSortType): Boolean;
begin
  Result := Sorted<T>(Values, Comparison<T>(SortType));
end;

class function TArray.Sorted<T>(var Values: array of T; const Comparison: TComparison<T>; Index, Count: Integer): Boolean;
var
  i: Integer;
begin
  for i := Index+1 to Index+Count-1 do begin
    if Comparison(Values[i-1], Values[i])>0 then begin
      Result := False;
      exit;
    end;
  end;
  Result := True;
end;

class function TArray.Sorted<T>(var Values: array of T; const Comparison: TComparison<T>): Boolean;
begin
  Result := Sorted<T>(Values, Comparison, 0, Length(Values));
end;

class function TArray.Sorted<T>(GetValue: TFunc<Integer, T>; const Comparison: TComparison<T>; Index, Count: Integer): Boolean;
var
  i: Integer;
begin
  for i := Index+1 to Index+Count-1 do begin
    if Comparison(GetValue(i-1), GetValue(i))>0 then begin
      Result := False;
      exit;
    end;
  end;
  Result := True;
end;
```

Answer (score 7):

Check neighbour pairs with the same comparator as Sort uses

```
Result := True;
for i := Low(Arr) + 1 to High(Arr) do
  if Compare(Arr[i], Arr[i - 1]) < 0 then
    Exit(False);
```

It takes O(n) time (against O(nlogn) for sorting)

Comment: Unless you find the array is not sorted, and then have to sort it anyway, in which case your efficiency is blown out the window anyway.

Comment: +1 In fact, [`TArray.Sort` uses quicksort](http://docs.embarcadero.com/products/rad_studio/delphiAndcpp2009/HelpUpdate2/EN/html/delphivclwin32/Generics_Collections_TArray_Sort@array_of_T.html), which in case of an almost/already sorted array [performs even worse](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2415193/11683) than O(nlogn).

Comment: @Ken White So author have to consider the most likely scenario - is array sorted most of the time?

Comment: Yes, that's what I said in my comment to the question. :-) (BTW, my comment to you came with a +1; if you do have the need to check, this would be the way to do it.)

Comment: @GSerg Actually, use of QuickSort doesn't guarantee worst case performance on almost/already sorted data. It also depends on how the implementation chooses its pivot element. Unfortunately I don't have a recent version of Delphi to check `TArray.Sort`, but if it uses `Classes.QuickSort`: that implementation pivots on the middle element. In which case an already sorted array is actually the optimal distribution for best performance.