# In quicksort If an array is randomized, does using the median of 3 for pivot selection matter?

Tags: algorithm, math, quicksort, timing

I've been comparing the run times of various pivot selection algorithms. Surprisingly the simplest one where the first element is always chosen is the fastest. This may be because I'm filling the array with random data.

If the array has been randomized (shuffled) does it matter? For example picking the medium of 3 as the pivot is always(?) better than picking the first element as the pivot. But this isn't what I've noticed. Is it because if the array is already randomized there would be no reason to assume sortedness, and using the medium is assuming there is some degree of sortedness?

Comment: If the array is shuffled , The worst case performance still can happen, but it depends only upon how unlucky we are.

Comment: I feel like you could just choose the pivot randomly and have the same effect. Didn't think about the case where there are duplicate elements too hard though, this could be a problem. Median of 3 is just a technique to make it harder to force quadratic worst case, when compared to a fixed-position pivot. The thing is, you don't want the randomization because it introduces non-deterministic runtimes and generating random numbers comes with a cost

Comment: @mohaned generally speaking that would require being very unlikely. The chances of the array being ordered in the worst case (that is fully sorted or reverse sorted) are much lower than it not being fully sorted/reverse sorted. Of course the more sorted an array is the harder it is for quicksort to sort, so I'm not sure...

Comment: @NiklasB. what does "non-deterministic runtimes" mean?

Comment: @Celeritas I think what happened with you because of shuffling O(n), it doesn't change total O(n lg n) but it takes additional time . the same problem (merge sort is also n lg n why quicksort runs faster in practice ?) because the time consumed in creating subarrays). Shuffling guarantees that array will be not sorted (if it were already shuffled this will only consume time), so worst case still can happen but with lower probability of course.

Comment: @mohaned I haven't been including the shuffling in the timing, only the sorting.

Comment: @Celeritas it varies between runs, while median of 3 is deterministic

Comment: Median-of-three will give you a slightly better partition on average for randomised data.  I don't know whether this will be reflected in the observed running times, but you're welcome to post your implementations and results.

Answer (score 1):

The worst case runtime of quicksort is `O(n²)`. Quicksort is only in average case a fast sorting algorithm.

To reach a **average** runtime of `O(n log n)` you have to choose a random pivot element.
But instead of choosing a random pivot element, you can shuffle the list and choose the first element.
To see that this holds you can look at this that way: lets say all elements are in a specific order. Shuffling means you use a random permutation on the list of elements, so a random element will be at the first position and also on all other positions. You can also see it by shuffling the list by randomly choose one of all elements for the first element, then choosing randomly one element of the other (not yet coosen elements) for the second element, and so on.

If your list is already a random generated list, you can directly choose the first element as pivot, without shuffling again.

So, choosing the first element is the fastest one because of the random generated input, but choosing the thrid or the last will also as fast as choosing the first.

All other ways to choose a pivot element have to compute something (a median or a random number or something like this), but they have no advantage over a random choice.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. You address my question head on in one sentence " If your list is already a random generated list, you can directly choose the first element as pivot, without shuffling again." could you please say more about that? For example, what is the proof that this is true?

Comment: I extended my answer a little bit :)

Comment: Nitpick: You get an average running time of O(n log n) just from quicksort.  You can turn that into an expected worst-case running time using randomisation as you describe.  The difference is that "average" means the average over all inputs, while "expected worst-case" means the worst over all inputs of the average over all random bit-strings.

Comment: Another nitpick: The asymptotics using big-O aren't fine enough to tease out the difference between "pick a random pivot" and "pick the median of three random pivots", but the difference will be reflected in the constant factor since the latter strategy tends to pick more balanced partitions while taking more time per recursive call.

Comment: The thing is that average running time of the deterministic algorithm is about the distribution of the input. But this heavily depends on where the algorithm is used. So by average running time i mean the expected running time of a randomized algorithm, depending on the distribution of its random bits. Computing now the median just kills a little bit randomness and gives me a little bit true knowledge about the input. but it costs some time to compute. There will be a n maximum number `k` such that computing the median of `k` random elements speeds the algorithm up by a constant factor.

Comment: But in this case the input is randomized, so computing some (e.g. 3) random numbers will take to long and kills the constant factor. But you could choose the first three elements an compute their median. This will give you an advantage of a constant factor. choosing random elements from a randomized list just dont give you more randomness^^

Comment: To reach the optimal runtime, you have to choose the pivot element such that exactly half of the unsorted values are smaller than the pivot and half are larger than the pivot (possibly using a fat pivot to group values equal to the pivot).  It's hard to tell which element is the best pivot, so we cheat. Choosing the first, last or middle element is vulnerable to poor performance on some data sets. Choosing at random avoids the poorest performance.  Nevertheless, choosing the median-of-3 random values gives you a better chance of choosing a good (or 'not bad') pivot, if the extra cost is OK.

Answer (score 1):

A substantially late response, but I believe it will add some additional info.

> Surprisingly the simplest one where the first element is always chosen
>   is the fastest.

This is actually not surprisingly at all, since you mentioned that you test the algorithm with the random data. In the reality, a percentage of almost-sorted and sorted data is much greater than it would statistically be expected. Take for example the chronological data, when you collect it into the log file some elements can be out of order, but most of them are already sorted. Unfortunately, the Quicksort implementation that takes first (or last) element as a pivot is vulnerable to such input and it degenerates into `O(n^2)` complexity because in the partition step you divide your array into two halves of size `1` and `n-1` and therefore you get `n` partitions instead of `log n`, on average.

That's why people decided to add some sort of randomization that would make a probability of getting the problematic input as minimum as possible. There are three well-known approaches:

- shuffle the input - to quote Robert Sedgewick, "the probability of getting `O(n^2)` performance with such approach is lower than the probability that you will be hit by a thunderstrike" :)
- choose the pivot element randomly - Wikipedia says that in average, expected number of comparisons in this case is `1.386 n log n`
- choose the pivot element as a median of three - Wikipedia says that in average, expected number of comparisons in this case is `1.188 n log n`

However, randomization **costs**. If you shuffle the input array, that is `O(n)` which is dominated by `O(nlogn)`, but you need to take in the account the cost of invoking `random(..)` method `n` times. With your simple approach, that is avoided and it is thus faster.

**See also:**

- [Worst case for Quicksort - when can it occur?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2415193/worst-case-for-quicksort-when-can-it-occur/24703473#24703473)