# Time performance of QuickSort

Tags: time, quicksort

QuickSort algorithm sorts 10.000.000 numbers. The running time was 5.3 seconds. I am wondering what is the running time if there were 1.000.000.000 numbers.

Is it logical to take about 681 seconds?

(It is a hypothetical question, so we don't depend on the computer's RAM or CPU perfomance.)

Comment: I suspect this is a great question for the computer science forum on here: http://cs.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The runtime of quicksort is, on average, O(n log n). Let's suppose that the runtime has the form c n log n for some constant c. You know that the runtime for n = 10,000,000 is 5.3s, so we get

> 10,000,000 c log 10,000,000 = 5.3s
>
> 10,000,000 c · 7 = 5.3s
>
> c = 75.71ns

So now let's plug in n = 1,000,000,000:

> c n log n =
>
> 75.71ns · 1,000,000,000 · log 1,000,000,000
>
> = 681.43s

So yes, your estimate is reasonable.

Answer (score 0):

Wikipedia page on Quicksort:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort

StackOverflow on Worst Case:
[Worst case for QuickSort - when can it occur?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2415193/worst-case-for-quicksort-when-can-it-occur)

Here it is answered on the math forum for complexity:
https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/96767/worst-case-complexity-of-the-quicksort-algorithm

Here is an answer about the time:
https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1071229/expected-time-of-quicksort?rq=1

Comment: While this is useful, does any of this directly answer the question?

Comment: I don't mean to just post links, but demonstrates this has already been asked and answered, and I think it's a great question, and wanted to share the links of where the question took me.    Having the actual ANSWER from @templatetypedef is useful too, and hopefully gets all the upvotes.  The key take-away that I hope your answer shares, is that this is a non-linear solution.