# Quicksort, given 3 values, how can I get to 9 operations?

Tags: quicksort

Well, I want to use Quick sort on given `3` values, doesn't matter what values, how can I get to the worst case which is `9` operations?

Can anyone draw a tree and show how it show `nlogn` and `n^2` operations? I've tried to find on the internet, but I still didnt manage to draw one properly to show that.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Worst case for QuickSort - when can it occur?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2415193/worst-case-for-quicksort-when-can-it-occur)

Answer (score 0):

The worst case complexity of quick sort depends on the chosen pivot. If the pivot chosen is the leftmost or the rightmost element. Then the worst case complexity will occur in the following cases:

1) Array is already sorted in same order.

2) Array is already sorted in reverse order.

3) All elements are same (special case of case 1 and 2).

Since these cases occur very frequently, the pivot is chosen randomly. By choosing pivot randomly the chances of worst case are reduced.

The analysis of quicksort algorithm is explained in [this](https://www.khanacademy.org/computing/computer-science/algorithms/quick-sort/a/analysis-of-quicksort) blogpost by khan academy.

Comment: I see, but how can I prove that with a tree that will yield 2 operations in good and average case, and 9 operations in worst case?

Comment: I found a blog post by khan academy that explains it mathematically. I have edited my answer with its link. You may have a look at it.

Comment: I looked there too. It didn't help much