# Sum biggest n numbers from unsorted array

Tags: algorithm

Just trying to solve this problem:

Given an unsorted array of integers, sum its biggest n numbers.

I did a TypeScript implementation, but of course this is language agnostic:

```js
const list_sum_largest_n_numbers = (list: Array<number> = [], n: number) => {
  let sum: number = 0;
  const sorted_list = list.sort((a, b) => a - b);

  for (let i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    let value_to_sum = sorted_list?.pop() || 0;
    sum += value_to_sum;
  }

  return sum;
};

let list = [17, 310, 32_432, 3, 2, 317, 34, 108_379];
let n = 3;

let result = list_sum_largest_n_numbers(list, n);
alert(result); // 141_128
```

Here in the [playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBANgS2gfQgVwLbLgQwE4DmApimMmJgEZF4QwC8MAFItAFwwCCeeOAngB4KGangB8DGAG0AugBoYYDsNEBKBhIDeAKBjwisdBmVUakgAwBuXTFCRDIPFCIATbEliNWUAHQRHUExMOAqU6vQSODAAtDBh1jYAZo7McAYwCBaWGTACitkIANSF6jp6emmwAG44cGhEyFAgqJiS-k6u7tAA-D4ADiB9TOoAPiMwVjZ6RjCFjDV1DU0tGNZ6AL7aNngGaHhgMEbW6wmV8B6SUgCMAOwKAMxX5g8ATMgALPcvDwrfMI93f7vBRPAAcyHuNwAnDJrGcDox7qd0jt0HBPOcUEZsPhiKRyKZaCwPAowKprLUaIFUWh0eSYAB6BkwK7vK7IK4vUFAA).

My first question is if, when solving this kind of problems, the use of the methods provided by the language —as `Array.sort()`— are allowed, or if I should implement everything by myself, keeping the solution low level.

Also, I am not sure that this is the best way to solve it. I would say that this is O(n), but I am not taking into account the `Array.sort()` method I'm using.

Comment: You can use the algorithm to find the max, but generalize it for n elements. You can think it like an array of n elements where you keep replacing the n max numbers until you reached the end

Comment: I don't think summing to change the essential problem to be *determining the biggest k items from an unordered array*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorting is already *O(n logn)*. It can be an easy solution when making use of the built-in sort functionality, but it is not going to be the most efficient solution to the problem.

#### Simple solution *O(kn)*

If you are looking for a more efficient yet simple solution for this problem, you can just keep picking out (and removing, or marking as visited) the biggest number *k* times, by iterating. You can sum them together as you go, without having to store them in a new array and iterate again. This would actually be *O(n)* per number, so ***O(kn)*** in total.

This will be more efficient for small or constant *k*. Of course, if for instance you know that *k = O(n)*, then better approaches exist.

#### Efficient solution *O(n)*

For a slightly less trivial solution, you can use [Quickselect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quickselect) to find the *k*th biggest number *x* and then in one iteration sum together all numbers greater than *x*, and then add *x* and possible remaining duplicate values (or as rici points out, iterate just on the right side of *x* because quickselect partitions the array to our benefit). This would give you a total time complexity of ***O(n)*** addition operations. It's a tradeoff between asymptotic performance and code complexity :)

#### On using built-in sort

As to whether it's ok to use built-in functions: Yes, definitely. Whenever they suit your purpose, it is better to use them than to reinvent the wheel every time. However, in an academic or challenge context, there might be rules in place disallowing use of libraries or built-in functions, for educational or competitive reasons.

Comment: Thanks @berthur, I really appreciate your explanation. I didn't though about using Quickselect, but now you mention it, is a similar problem. Below @chux proposed using a binary priority queue. I didn't understand very well this solution, but apparently that would be `O(m·log(n))`. That would make it more efficient than using quickselect, which would be `O(k·n)`?

Comment: Very glad @EmilleC. that you found my answer helpful :) If low time complexity is what you are after, I edited the answer to add another approach that should require only O(n) on average. My original suggestion doesn't require quickselect, as you can just pick out the largest value on each iteraton. This should be very simple to implement.  As for chux' answer I'm sure a priority queue can be a nice tool here as well, although I admit I also didn't quite understand their steps.

Comment: Quickselect might be better called quickpartition, because it actually does partition the array. After you call quickselect(array, p), the all the values at indices less than p are at most array[p] and all the values with indices greater than p are at least array[p]. (Or you can do it the other way around). So to find the sum, you just sum the appropriate partition plus the value at index p.

Comment: @rici Good point, it makes the algorithm even simpler. Your *p* is what I call *x* in my description above. Notice though that if there are several duplicates of *x*, you have to keep count of how many times you need to add *x* into your sum. Still O(n).

Comment: @Berthur I'm not sure if I understood your answer right. «then in one iteration sum together all numbers greater than x»: if I'm not mistaken you are solving the problem of summing the numbers greater than n, instead of summing the biggest n numbers.

Comment: @EmilleC. If you pick the biggest number *k* times (and obv. remove it or mark it as visited), then you have picked out the *k* largest numbers, haven't you? :)

Comment: The O(n) solution using quicksort is a different algorithm. Asymptitically faster but more difficult to implement. Here you get the *k*th largest number once by running quickselect, call this number *x*. Then you iterate once and compare with *x* (or like @rici says, which is even simpler).

Comment: @Berthur I was refering to the quickselect variant. But now I realize it is correct, as @rici says: you partition the list by the kth biggest number, so the left partition has all lower numbers, and the right partition has all greater numbers, having a length of `k - 1`. The sum of these numbers plus the kth greater number is the response.

Comment: Now my question is: Quickselect has a worst case performance of  О(n^2). Shouldnt be this considered the performance of this solution?

Comment: @EmilleC. That is a good question. This is a widely discussed phenomenon, see the analogous Quicksort algorithm. I think I am wiser to refer you to those qualified discussions than to try to sum them up here. For example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2415193/worst-case-for-quicksort-when-can-it-occur

Comment: Thanks @Berthur. I see that the secret relies on the «unsorted array of integers» part of the question. It is a tradeoff: using quickselect, for an unsorted list we get an average case of `Θ(n)`, which is better than the `O(n * log(m))` of the proposal given in the answer by @chux using a priority queue. But if the list is sorted, then quickselect will end up with the worst case scenario, which is`O(n^2)`, while the version using priority queue algorithm will still be `O(n * log(m))`, which is significantly better. So the better algorithm depends on the context of the input data. Am I right?

Comment: @EmilleC. Something like that :) Although, you can avoid those unfortunate/malicious inputs by using randomness to your advantage. Then, the probability of encountering a worst-case scenario decreases exponentially with *n*.

Answer (score 1):

Given array `a[m]` and looking for the `n` greatest:

1. If `m <= n`, we are done.

When `m` is significantly more than `n`: cost `O(m * log(n))`.

1. Form a [binary priority queue](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Priority_queue) `p[n]`.  Insertion is `O(log(n))`, deletion is `O(log(n))`, and examining the smallest is `O(1)`.
2. Iterate `a[]` and when `a[i]` is greater than the smallest in `p[]`, remove smallest and add `a[i]`.

Otherwise simple sort `a[]` with cost `O(m * log(m))`

---

Some code to get OP started:  (Scant error checking, not optimized.)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

static void pq_enqueue(size_t current_size, int *pq, int value) {
  size_t child = current_size;
  while (child > 0) {
    size_t parent = (child + 1) / 2 - 1;
    if (pq[parent] <= value) {
      break;
    }
    pq[child] = pq[parent];
    child = parent;
  }
  pq[child] = value;
}

static int pq_dequeue(size_t current_size, int *pq) {
  int v = pq[0];
  size_t root = 0;
  for (;;) {
    size_t lchild = (root + 1) * 2 - 1;
    size_t rchild = (root + 1) * 2 + 1 - 1;
    if (lchild >= current_size) {
      break;
    }
    int lvalue = pq[lchild];
    int rvalue = rchild < current_size ? pq[rchild] : INT_MAX;
    if (lvalue <= rvalue) {
      pq[root] = lvalue;
      root = lchild;
    } else {
      pq[root] = rvalue;
      root = rchild;
    }
  }
  if (root + 1 < current_size) {
    pq[root] = pq[current_size - 1];
    size_t child = root;
    int value = pq[root];
    while (child > 0) {
      size_t parent = (child + 1) / 2 - 1;
      if (pq[parent] <= value) {
        break;
      }
      pq[child] = pq[parent];
      child = parent;
    }
    pq[child] = value;
  }
  return v;
}

static clock_t test_pq(size_t n, int buf[n], size_t top_n) {
  clock_t c0 = clock();

  for (size_t i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    buf[i] = rand();
  }

  int top[top_n];
  for (size_t i = 0; i < top_n; i++) {
    pq_enqueue(i, top, buf[i]);
  }
  for (size_t i = top_n; i < n; i++) {
    if (buf[i] >= top[0]) {
      pq_dequeue(top_n--, top);
      pq_enqueue(top_n++, top, buf[i]);
    }
  }

  long long sum = 0;
  for (size_t i = 0; i < top_n; i++) {
    if (i < 3) {
      ; // printf("%zu: %d\n", i, top[i]);
    }
    sum += top[i];
  }

  clock_t c1 = clock();
  printf("n:%11zu, top_n:%5zu, sum: %15lld ticks:%9lld\n", n, top_n, sum,
      (long long) (c1 - c0));
  return c1 - c0;
}

int main() {
  printf("RAND_MAX:%d\n", RAND_MAX);
  size_t N = 1000000000;
  int *buf = malloc(sizeof *buf * N);
  if (buf) {
    for (size_t n = 1000000; n <= N; n *= 10) {
      test_pq(n, buf, 3);
    }
    for (size_t t = 4; t <= 1000; t *= 4) {
      test_pq(N, buf, t);
    }
    free(buf);
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Output

```
RAND_MAX:2147483647
n:    1000000, top_n:    3, sum:      6442444824 ticks:       16
n:   10000000, top_n:    3, sum:      6442450334 ticks:       78
n:  100000000, top_n:    3, sum:      6442450883 ticks:      797
n: 1000000000, top_n:    3, sum:      6442450934 ticks:     7891
n: 1000000000, top_n:    4, sum:      8589934585 ticks:     6610
n: 1000000000, top_n:   16, sum:     34359737961 ticks:     6593
n: 1000000000, top_n:   64, sum:    137438948345 ticks:     6610
n: 1000000000, top_n:  256, sum:    549755742014 ticks:     6578
```

Notice that as the array size grow by 10, the time also grows by 10.

As the top N grows by 4, the time does not grow, as with random data, nearly all values are less than the top few and do not encounter a growing cost.  So I guess a poor test case to demo the `log(top_n)` in the `O(n * log(top_n))`.  When `top_n` is much less than `n` and random data, we approach `O(n)`.  Hmmm, will review later.

Comment: If I understood right,your solution using a binary priority queue is `O(m·log(n))`. Given that the solution proposed by @berthur using quicksort is `O(k·n)`: the one with binary priority queue is better?

Comment: @EmilleC. O(m·log(n)) is better  than O(k·n) for [limiting behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation).

Comment: Hm, «limiting behaviour» refers to the big O notation itself, right? Or does it refer to the behaviour for a specific subset of inputs?

Comment: @EmilleC. Not a specific subset of inputs.  As `n, m` grow, the time for arbitrary values grow per `O(m * log(n))`.

Comment: Thanks @chux. Also, when you refer to a binary priority queue, you mean an implementation using a heap instead of a list to keep performance `log(n)`, right?

Comment: @EmilleC. By _binary priority queue_, I mean a binary tree.  That binary tree may be implemented with a [simple array](https://www.programiz.com/dsa/priority-queue).

Comment: Thanks @chux. but I don't get it: a tree is a hierarchical structure, while an array is a linear one. Always though that they were exclusive.

Comment: @EmilleC. Think of a _binary_ tree where the root is a `a[1]`, its 2 children are at `a[2], a[3]`, the children of any node `a[i]` has children at `a[i*2], a[i2 + 1]`...

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica I also don't quite get it :) Should I not populate `p` before accessing it in step 2? Do I fill it with `n` numbers from `a` similarly to Lajos' answer or?

Comment: Try to give time assessment some warm-up - I suggest 5 seconds even as the drop in ticks from 3 to 4 is suggestive.

Comment: `When m is not significantly more than n simply sort` *unless* `n` is close to `m`: Subtract the m-n lowest values from the total sum here.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I will not delve into the question whether you are allowed to call library sort or not. This is up to you and your professor/boss/task.

Instead, I will delve into the question of whether you *should* do it. Imagine a case when you have 1 000 000 items in your array. The initial sort only has an **O(n * log(n))** complexity (where n represents the number of items in your array), which is a high cost. Additionally, you have an **O(m)** complexity after the sort to calculate the sum of the first/last m elements, depending on the direction of the sort (where m represents the number of items to sum), so, in total, the complexity is of

**O(m + n * log(n))**

Below I describe my initial approach, and then an improvement, suggested by @Elliott in the comment section.

## 1. Taking the first n item

Create an array, let's call it `output` (and the input will be called `input` here). Copy the first n (unsorted) elements from `input` into `output`.

## 2. Sort output

Yes, this is an algorithm of nlog(n) complexity, but your `output` is likely to be much smaller than your `input`.

## 3. Continue the loop

Continue looping your `input` from the (n+1)th element and for each element compare it with the smallest element in `output` (this is why we sorted `output`). If the smallest element of `output` is greater than the current element, then do nothing in this iteration. Otherwise find the greatest element of `output` that is still smaller than the current element, shift everything smaller to the left in `output` and put the current element into its right place.

Example logic in Javascript

```
function(item, output) {
    let highestIndex = -1;
    while ((output[highestIndex + 1] < item) && (highestIndex + 1 < output.length)) highestIndex++;
    if (highestIndex >= 0) {
        for (let index = 0; index < highestIndex; index++) output[index] = output[index + 1];
    output[highestIndex] = item;
    }
}
```

## 4. Take into account edge cases

- if n is 0, then the result is 0, no need for any loop
- if n equals the length of `input`, then just sum `input`
- if n is negative or greater than the length of `input`, throw an error

These edge cases are important, you can easily increase performance for them.

## Improvement based on Elliott's suggestion

Even though it is probable that the number of elements to sum will frequently be of low value, in the case when there are many items to sum, my initial approach, described in earlier sections can contribute to the complexity and there is further room for improvement.

As Elliott, quite correctly pointed out, my stack-based approach has a linear complexity (if the number of elements to sum can be great) and he also suggested an improvement, which is to use an [AVL tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AVL_tree) to store the highest numbers so far.

If that approach would be taken, then the idea would change the way we handle the greatest numbers found so far. Whenever we process a new element, we could search for it in the AVL tree (O(log(m)) complexity), removing the smallest element (if the new element is greater), adding the new element and inserting the new element into this self-balancing tree.

This is a more complicate, but more efficient approach, that is, it is less complex in time than the one I initially proposed. Thanks, Elliott for the suggestions for improvement!

Comment: @Elliott thanks for providing suggestions for improvement, I have edited my answer accordingly.

Comment: @Elliott: why use an AVL tree instead of a priority queue as proposed by Chux in his answer?